# Is there a .replace substring that expresses "directory" instead of "specific directory"?

Tags: python, path

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Choose a Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
    song = song.replace(string that means path, "")
    song_box.insert(END, song)
```

Instead of this:

```
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Choose a Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
    song = song.replace("C:/specifically/stated/path", "")
    song_box.insert(END, song)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the file name from a path?  That's `os.path.basename`.

Comment: I am asking how to display just the file name of the song in a playlist box without having to type the specific path in the code for the player.

Comment: I found an answer to what I needed to do in case anyone comes across this with the same question:

Comment: `code`
def add_song():
    song = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title="Choose a Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
    song = song.split("/")[-1].split('.')[0]
    song_box.insert(END, song)
`code`

Comment: That's exactly the same as `os.path.basename`, which will work even with Windows filenames, where your code won't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to extract the file name from a path.  That's what `os.basename` is for.